# Imperfect test sensitivity...what does 0% prevalence really mean?

Tags: distributions, sensitivity-specificity

I'm trying to think about test sensitivity and specificity in a theoretical disease-host system.

Say you have a population from which you take a sample and test for the pathogen of interest using a diagnostic test that can detect whether or not that particular pathogen is present at 5% prevalence or more within the system with 95% certainty.

You calculate the required sample size, perform the diagnostic tests, and get a 0% prevalence rate. Technically, what have I found? I can say I'm 95% sure that the pathogen is not prevalent at 5% or higher, but can I say anything more beyond that? What do I know about the probability that the disease is 1% or 4% prevalent?

Basically, I'm trying to fit a probability distribution to the prevalences below that detection threshold. I'm leaning towards using a uniform distribution between 0-4% actual prevalence, because my test doesn't give me any more information about prevalence, but I wanted to get some input here.

Comment: What you need is better information of the ROC curve type for the test. Basically, what happens is that at a certain low prevalence, the false positive results begin to be problematic. However, with an ROC type analysis, you can figure it out.

Comment: I don't have any of that information unfortunately. I know the numbers are generated from a hypergeometric distribution...could I generate a hyper geometric distribution and just look at the tail of the graph to see what's going on down there?

Comment: Since the whole problem is theoretical, you should indeed use the whole model to answer your question.  However, to ask a question here without giving the details limits the answers to guesswork.